# worst latency for single message

Tags: centos, ubuntu-16.04, zeromq

I have a requirement to build a real-time-low-latency messaging system.

I read up ZeroMQ guide, for my requirement `ROUTER-DEALER` pattern matches perfectly. I built the system around it and it is working fine. But when I am doing performance testing I found ZeroMQ latency is staggeringly high.

libzmq version : 4.2.5

```
./local_lat  tcp://127.0.0.1:5555 1 1000
./remote_lat tcp://127.0.0.1:5555 1 1000

message size:       1 [B]
roundtrip count: 1000
average latency:   26.123 [us]
```

When the message count is high, ZeroMQ performance is awesome, but when the same message count is 1 the latency is quite high.

```
./local_lat  tcp://127.0.0.1:5555 1 1
./remote_lat tcp://127.0.0.1:5555 1 1

message size:      1 [B]
roundtrip count:   1
average latency: 506.500 [us]
```

Still not convienced I took the `PUB-SUB` example from ZeroMQ guide modified to `ROUTER-DEALER` and added a timestamp and tested again. There is also the latency really very high. This makes ZeroMQ unusable. I agree when the message volumes are high there is nothing which will beat ZeroMQ, but for the systems where the latency is critical even for single message ZeroMQ fails.

Note : I ran the `PUB-SUB` example also, it is showing me same latency figures

sender.cpp

```
 #include <zmq.hpp>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main () {

    //  Prepare our context and publisher
    zmq::context_t context (1);
    zmq::socket_t publisher (context, ZMQ_ROUTER);
    publisher.bind("tcp://*:5556");

    //wait for peer to connect
    //once connected store the identity to send message later
    zmq::message_t identity,m;
    publisher.recv(&identity);//identity
    publisher.recv(&m);//message
    sleep(1);//sleep to set up connections
    struct timeval timeofday;
    int i=1;//no of messages to send
    while (i) {
      zmq::message_t id,message("10101",5);
      id.copy(&identity);
        gettimeofday(&timeofday,NULL);
    publisher.send(id,ZMQ_SNDMORE);
        publisher.send(message);

    std::cout << timeofday.tv_sec << ", " << timeofday.tv_usec << std::endl;
        usleep(1);
    --i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

reciever.cpp

```
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    zmq::context_t context (1);

      zmq::socket_t subscriber (context, ZMQ_DEALER);
       subscriber.setsockopt(ZMQ_IDENTITY,"1",1);
       subscriber.connect("tcp://localhost:5556");

    struct timeval timeofday;
    subscriber.send(" ",1);
    int update_nbr;
    int i=1;
    for (update_nbr = 0; update_nbr < i; update_nbr++) {

        zmq::message_t update;

        subscriber.recv(&update);

    gettimeofday(&timeofday,NULL);
        std::cout << timeofday.tv_sec << ", " << timeofday.tv_usec << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

sender output

```
1562908600, 842072
```

reciever output

```
1562908600, 842533
```

As you can see it takes about 400 ms.

Is there any way to reduce the latency?

Comment: Would you mind to add a copy or citation from the Real-Time System Detailed Specification Document, what was the actual design-target, defining the range of the acceptable message-delivery latencies ( for worst-case conditions and for other workloads envelopes ) - i.e. what explicit requirement for such ranges of latencies was actually set as specified in the original Real-Time System Detailed Specification Document and/or what other design-side constraints were defined in the requirements for implementation of such a Real-Time System behaviour?

Comment: @user3666197 no i cannot provide any document.The important thing is messages should flow from module A to B at the lowest latency as possible.It is a very time senstive applications.Whatever latencies am getting here is huge.When there is huge volume of message,system works exeedingly good.Problem is only when there is a single messages

Comment: The question was clear - not to provide "The Document", but to cite, what amount of message-delivery latency the System specification defined in the requirements (  how many [us] are within the spec of the guaranteed Real-Time System, to operate stable and as defined in the RTS-DSpec Document ( The more, when it is "**a very time sensitive application**" - where the exact requirements from the system detailed specification document define, what such latency is within spec and what is not ). **" Having no target, indeed any road may fit ... "**

Comment: What exactly is not clear here? . Am saying Process A sends a message to process B. The message recieved to B is taking around 400ms.ideally latency should be less than 150ms. I have provided sample code you can compile and check yourself the latency figures

Comment: Any solutions or tunings?

Comment: Try to snif the network traffic to determine whether the delay is at the sender (server) side or receiver (client) side. It is possible that the server does not immediately send the message, for example when using ZMQ_SNDMORE or TCP's Nagle's algorithm.

Comment: @rveerd it is a single message. And Nagle algorithm is disabled. How to snif the network?

Comment: @NagarajuSherigar On Linux you can use tcpdump. Make sure you specify the correct interface to snif localhost (`-i lo`).

Answer (score 0):

The overhead of setting up a TCP connection is not trivial - and the overhead increases for ZMQ, because the action of creating a connection is accomplished, behind the scenes, with some TCP back-and-forth.

So, the latency of your *first* message is not just the latency of the message itself.  It's the latency of the message combined with the latency of the messages involved in setting up the connection.

The other thing to note is that 1 byte is a *staggeringly* inefficient payload, even with vanilla TCP.  If ZMQ is doing *any* sort of batching when it sends, that'll dramatically improve latency of a large number of messages.  I don't know if it does any of that under the hood or not, but the fact remains that 1 byte is saddled with the same unavoidable overhead involved with both TCP and ZMQ to establish the connection as 1000 bytes is, it just overwhelms the latency involved with sending the 1 byte and is negligible for 1000 bytes.

I recommend you send 2 messages and watch the individual latency for each message - if I'm right, the 2nd one should be back down into the ~25µs range.  If that's the case, then it's up to you whether that overhead represents a problem or not.  I suspect it won't in practice.

Comment: it is not a 1 byte message.am taking about a single message of any size. It is not during handshaking, because handshaking happens when the device connects. And my application waits for around 10sec for every new connection 
 before actually sending or receiving message. This patterns repeats throughout the runtime when there was a single message passed from one end to another

Comment: @NagarajuSherigar ZeroMQ sockets are not just TCP sockets with fancy names. They do not necessarily connect (on the TCP level) when you call `connect()`. For example, they could delay connection until there is data to send.

Comment: @rveerd fine then the latency should be there for the very first message sent. Here am saying it is there for every message. Note latency is there only when a single message(not single byte) is passed, when there is a high volume of messages sent then is not delay

Comment: @NagarajuSherigar you seem to be saying contradictory things. You say the latency is there for every message, but noly when there is one message, not many messages.  That is consistent with it being there for only the first message.  Have you tried what I suggested, sending not one or many messages, but two messages?  Are you certain the 2nd message carries high latency?

Comment: @NagarajuSherigar I made certain assumptions, since you don't show any of your code that what you did show us was representative.  It appears that's not the case.  So I suggest you share your actual code, then other people might be able to suggest actual problems?

Comment: @jason when 2 messages are sent at the same time latency is less.but if I put a delay between the 2 messages both the messages have higher latency

Comment: @jason I can't show the code since it is my company's property. I made a sample example which I posted here. You can run and see. Output is timestamped  so it is not difficult to understand

Answer (score 0):

ZMQ does not send messages serially, ie there is not a 1:1 relationship between zmq_send() and the send() function on the underlying TCP socket.  As a message queue it gives the buffer the chance to fill at least some between actual sends over TCP. This delay is very minimal, but effective enough to allow many msgs to be sent at once, potentially utilizing the whole bandwidth available between two points. If I'm not mistaken ZMQ's IO will automatically tune itself to maximize throughput while maintaining as little latency as possible if the buffer isn't filling between sends. So true latency may be as high as 100 ms or even more if over TCP, but is actually sending thousands of messages at once if the queue is being fed fast enough.